# Extractor with pattern matching

Tags: scala

This Scala code

```
object Twice {
  def apply(x: Int): Int = x * 2
  def unapply(z: Int): Option[Int] = if (z%2 == 0) Some(z/2) else None
}

object TwiceTest extends App {
  val x = Twice(5)
  println(x)
  x match { case Twice(n) => println(n) }
}
```

prints

```
10
5
```

when TwiceTest is run. Question is: `x` is an integer and not a function `Twice(n)`, so why the pattern matching works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the pattern matching expression.

Let's take a look at it:

```
x match {
  case Twice(n) => println(n)
}
```

You are matching using `Twice`. In the background, it will call `Twice.unapply()` with parameter `x`. If the result is `Some(foo)`, it will substitute the value of `foo` into the value of `n`. Otherwise it won't match.

See [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html) for longer explanation.

Comment: So a `case` pattern will always invoke an `unapply` function?

Comment: @ps0604 Yes, if used in this form. But `case` has other forms, too, for example
`x match { case n: Int => println(n)}`. This will only test the type, it won't do pattern-matching.

Answer (score 1):

Patterns as such have nothing to do with objects or encapsulation. The whole semantics of a Pattern is given by the unapply-method of the object of that name. This has to be a function from some type you want to match on to an optional. It matches, if the apply function returns something. You can match on any type and return value you want.

In your case your unapply-method takes an integer and returns an other integer if successful. It does not matter, that the object Twice also has an apply method and it does not matter, where the integer came from.

You can even remove the apply-method an still do this

```
8 match { case Twice(n) => println(n) }
```

it will work as well.

The compiler just transforms this into something like

```
val temp = Twice.unapply(8)
if(temp.isDefined) {
  val n = temp.get
  println(n)
}
```

(Probably something more complicated as it has to be more general to support all features of patterns.)